# Почему не парсятся данные с сайта socialblade?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Данные которые хочу спарсить:

[image: Спарсить div]

Мой код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'
      }
features="html.parser"
url='https://socialblade.com/youtube/top/50/mostsubscribed'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, features)
r.encoding = 'utf-8'

with open('test.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(r.text)

href_youtubers = soup.find_all({'style': 'float: right; width: 900px;'})
print(href_youtubers)
```

Проблема:
Парсер выдает пустой список.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо:

```
soup.find_all({"style": "float: right; width: 900px;"})
```

используйте:

```
soup.find_all('div', attrs={'style': 'float: right; width: 900px;'})
```