# Ошибка при парсинге socialblade

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

**Что хочу спарсить:** Все ссылки ютуберов [image: Все ссылки ютуберов]

**Мой код:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'
          }
features="html.parser"
url='https://socialblade.com/youtube/top/50/mostsubscribed'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
name_cards = []
r.encoding = 'utf-8'

with open('list_youtube.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(r.text)

href_youtubers = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'style': 'float: right; width: 900px;'})
href_yotubers = href_youtubers.find_all("a", href=True)
print(href_youtubers)
```

**Ошибка:**

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements  
like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Не понимаю, вообще, в чем ошибка, все перепробовал.

**Приму,  любую помощь.**

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не парсятся данные с сайта socialblade](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1219195/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-socialblade)

Comment: @Jack_oS Ну какой он дубликат! Повнимательнее, пожалуйста, посмотрите.

Comment: Переведите ошибку на русский и будет вам счастье

Comment: @Skeggi сделал просто find и AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: теперь вам осталось понять почему у вашего объекта нет атрибутов `find()` и `find_all()`

Comment: @Skeggi  не понимаю

Comment: @Skeggi из-за того что href_youtubers список?

Comment: @Dmitry зачем плодить вопросы? почему бы не дополнить ваш https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1219195/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-socialblade